# replace the unnecessary double quotation marks in the text field

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to replace the unnecessary double quotation marks in the names without a double quotation. For now, I know the names But I wanted the code to be dynamic. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
$FilePath = "C:\Test\"
Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Filter | ForEach-Object {
(Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) | Foreach-Object {
$_ -replace  ',"Frederick "Fred"",' , ',"Frederick Fred",' `
-replace  ',"Brian "Josiah"",' , ',"Brian Josiah",' ` 
-replace  ',""",' , ',"",'
} | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample input file? (raw text please)

Comment: which version of PoSh do you need? please don't spam the Question with unneeded tags ...

Answer (score 2):

Use a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions):

```sh
# Sample input
$str = '"Frederick "Fred"","Brian "Josiah"",""""'

$str -replace '(?m)(?<=,|^)"([^,"]*)"([^,"]*)""(?=,|$)', '"$1$2"'
```

Output:

```sh
"Frederick Fred","Brian Josiah",""
```

For an explanation of the regex and the chance to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/ngXGHe/1) (note that the `"` chars. on the linked page are escaped as `\"`, because the regex as a whole is enclosed in `"..."`, unlike in `'...'`, as above).

Answer (score 0):

here's a way to get rid of unwanted double quotes that does not use [mind melting for some of us] regex. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
$TwoDoubleQuotes = '""'
$OneDoubleQuote = '"'
$SpaceDQ = ' "'
$Space = ' '

$InString = '"Frederick "Fred"","Brian "Josiah"",""""'
$OutString = $InString.Replace($TwoDoubleQuotes, $OneDoubleQuote).Replace($SpaceDQ, $Space)

$InString
$OutString
```

the output ...

```
"Frederick "Fred"","Brian "Josiah"",""""
"Frederick Fred","Brian Josiah",""
```

what the code does ...

- defines some really simple minded constants
  the string patterns are hard for me to read, so this bypasses that. [*grin*]
- defines the inbound string
- chains the `.Replace()` string method
  that replaces the `2xDQ` with `1xDQ` and then replaces the `SpaceDQ` with just a `Space`.
- saves the new string to a $Var
- displays both the old & new string for your viewing pleasure